# Converting an int into an array without converting it to a String

Tags: java, arrays, int

I am programming in Java and want to convert an int into an array. For example I want to convert 122 into {1, 2, 2}. Do you have an idea how this works? Thanks in advance. I am not allowed to convert it into a string.

Comment: @udiboy1209 no. There is no possibility to use string

Answer (score 3):

The following example uses pure arithmetical approach (without converting the number to string):

```
int number = 122;
List<Integer> digitList = new LinkedList<>();

while(number > 0) {
  int d = number % 10; //get last digit
  digitList.add(0, d);
  number = number / 10; //omit last digit
}

Integer[] digits = digitList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not allowed to use math. functions - how can I do it without that?

Comment: Refactor the for loop to be a recursive function which skips if your 10based index is bigger than your number

Comment: Since you cannot use math you should find a method of get number of digits of the value. You can either implement your own log10 or do something like &#39;length=0;i=value;while(i:10&gt;0.9){i=i/10;length++;}'

Comment: @Z.Wo I updated the code, that doesn't use Math and length of the number.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer without using `Math` class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class int_to_array
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        int number = 122;
        int length=0;
        int org=number;
        while(org!=0)
        {
            org=org/10;
            length++;
        }
        int[] array = new int[length];

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          int rem = number % 10; 
          array[length - i - 1] = rem;
          number = number / 10; 
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will just implement your idea and test it.

Comment: When I am implement this it seems to end up in an endless loop:

Answer (score 1):

This ends up in an endless loop - why that?

```
    int input = readInt("Bitte geben Sie eine positive Zahl ein:");
    while(input < 0) {
        input = readInt("Bitte geben Sie eine positive Zahl ein:");
    }
    int number = input;
    int length = 0;
    int org = number;
    while(org != 0) {
        org = org / 10;
        length++;
    }
    int[] inputArray = new int[length];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < inputArray.length) {
        int rem = number % 10;
        inputArray[length - i - 1] = rem;
        number = number / 10;
 i++;
    }
    String output = "{";
    i = 0;
    while(i < inputArray.length) {
        output += inputArray[i];
        if(i < inputArray.length-1) {
            output += ", ";
        }
        i++;
    }
    output += "}";
    System.out.print(output);
```

Comment: I have edited your code, check it now

Comment: This is perfect!!!! Great. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted